# Rails 3 sending and receiving email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email

In my Rails 3 application I have an activity model which includes a has_many association with a participant model. I'd like to implement comment functionality so that when a comment is created an email is sent to all participants and when a participant replies to the email that reply is added to the activity as a further comment. When sending out the emails I'd like to use a dynamic reply-to address (eg. activity-345@mydomain.com) that can be used to identify the source activity.

I have found a useful [blog post](http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/) covering various options for receiving email in Rails 3 though this is a couple of years old now. It would seem that the most viable solutions are to use a mail server like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) and then either execute a ruby script to send emails to my app via an HTTP POST or poll for emails using the [mailman](https://github.com/titanous/mailman) gem; or to use a third party like [CloudMailin](http://www.cloudmailin.com/) or [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) to send emails to my app via an HTTP POST.

I was just wondering if anyone could offer any advice or recommendations based on solutions that they have used for sending/receiving email.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony) - it's a really simple to use e-mail gem that can be set up to use an external SMTP (like Gmail).  I've used it on a couple of my sites and it's pretty solid.